# first query is sending data even though the last query is failing in a multiple query set up

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to pass multiple query for execution for which i don't want data from 1st query to execute if the last query is having issues.

```
$user = Gateway::user()->storeDoctorUser(\Input::all(), 'doctor'); 
$address = Gateway::address()->storeDoctorAddress(\Input::all(), $user->id);
$doctors = Gateway::doctor()->storeDoctorData(\Input::all(), $user->id,$address->id);
```

As stated above how to solve this issue.If somehow the doctor query is failing then also user and address are working ,which should not happen .If the last one fails all should fail.

Comment: Check out Database Transactions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#database-transactions

Comment: No i can't use this one because the query i am referencing from these methods lies in different pages

Comment: in different classes, or different http requests? If all 3 of those calls are made in the same http request, you should be able to use transactions ok?

Comment: all 3 are there in different classes.

Comment: Even if they're in 3 different classes, they all use the same database connection. Transactions are dependant on connection, not class.

Comment: Thanks.issue resolved.